# create a list of tuples from csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples

I am python beginner struggling to create and save a list containing tuples from csv file in python.

The code I got for now is:

```
def load_file(filename):
    fp = open(filename, 'Ur')
    data_list = []
    for line in fp:
        data_list.append(line.strip().split(','))
    fp.close()
    return data_list
```

and then I would like to save the file

```
def save_file(filename, data_list):
    fp = open(filename, 'w')
    for line in data_list:
        fp.write(','.join(line) + '\n')
    fp.close()
```

Unfortunately, my code returns a list of lists, not a list of tuples... Is there a way to create one list containing multiple tuples without using csv module?

Comment: Unless I'm missing some subtle point - all you're doing is copying the file?

Comment: why not using the csv module ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`split` returns a list, if you want a tuple, convert it to a tuple:

```
    data_list.append(tuple(line.strip().split(',')))
```

Please use the `csv` module.

Answer (score 7):

First question: why is a list of lists bad? In the sense of "duck-typing", this should be fine, so maybe you think about it again.

If you really need a list of tuples - only small changes are needed.

Change the line

```
        data_list.append(line.strip().split(','))
```

to

```
        data_list.append(tuple(line.strip().split(',')))
```

That's it.

If you ever want to get rid of custom code (less code is better code), you could stick to the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)-module. I'd strongly recommend using as many library methods as possible.

To show-off some advanced Python features: your `load_file`-method could also look like:

```
def load_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'Ur') as fp:
        data_list = [tuple(line.strip().split(",") for line in fp]
```

I use a list comprehension here, it's very concise and easy to understand.

Additionally, I use the `with`-statement, which will close your file pointer, even if an exception occurred within your code. Please always use `with` when working with external resources, like files.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap "tuple()" around the `line.strip().split(',')` and you'll get a list of tuples.  You can see it in action in [this runnable gist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/gists/5237115/load_tuples.py/ipython2/?affiliate_id=000003ec).